# Java Regular expression 5

Tags: java, regex

I have to write one regular expression with requirement below,

> if ] preceding with non white space character then put a space after ]

```
input = hello man [u-12-d-g]how are you
output = hello man [u-12-d-g] how are you
```

I am using `msg = msg.replaceAll("]\\S", "] ");` but it just delete  succeeding character

> hello man [u-12-d-g] ow are you

Comment: what have you tired? what did you research? what is troubling you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a capturing group. Basic example (note the brackets `()` around `\\S`):

```
String input = "hello man [u-12-d-g]how are you";
String output = input.replaceAll("](\\S)", "] $1");
System.out.println(output);
input = "hello man [u-12-d-g] how are you";
output = input.replaceAll("](\\S)", "] $1");
System.out.println(output);
```

`$1` will match whatever comes after the `]` and you can use it in your replacement. Above will output:

```
hello man [u-12-d-g] how are you
hello man [u-12-d-g] how are you
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with negative lookahead:

```
var re = /](?!>[^\s])/; 
var str = 'hello man [u-12-d-g]how are you';
var subst = '] '; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```